# Client side javascript, creation of several elements and show each asap

Tags: javascript, html, document, appendchild

Client side javascript code creates some elements (about 50-100) in a cycle:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   var obj = document.createElement("DIV");
   obj.innerHTML = "<span class=\"itemId\">" + list[i].Id 
                   + "</span><!-- some more simple code --> ";

   mainObj.appendChild(obj);
}
```

There are some problems with browser rendering. For example, IE just freezes until it finishes the cycle, and then shows all elements at once. Is there a way to show each created element separately and immediately after `appendChild()`?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive - use length instead of 'Length'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert a delay between adding successive entries, with `setTimeout()`.

```
function insertEntry(list, ix) {
    if (ix == null) {
        ix = 0;
    }
    else if (ix < list.length) {
        var elt= document.createElement("DIV");
        var attr = document.createAttribute('id');
        attr.value = 'item'+ix;
        elt.setAttributeNode(attr);
        elt.innerHTML = "<span class='itemCls'>" + list[ix].Id + ':&nbsp;' + list[ix].Name +
            "</span><!-- some more simple code -->\n";
        mainObj.appendChild(elt);
        ix++;
    }
    if (ix < list.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){insertEntry(list, ix);}, 20);
    }
}
```

Kick it off with:

```
    insertEntry(myList);
```

where myList is like this:

```
var myList = [
    { Id : '1938377', Name : 'Sven'},
    { Id : '1398737', Name : 'Walt'},
    { Id : '9137387', Name : 'Edie'}
    ...
 };
```

demo:  http://jsbin.com/ehogo/4

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the single threaded nature of browsers.  Rendering will not begin until the thread becomes idle.  In this case, it's when your loop has completed and the function exits.  The only way around this is to (sort of) simulate multiple threads using timers, like so:

```
var timer,
    i = 0,
    max = list.length;

timer = window.setInterval(function ()
{
    if (i < max)
    {
        var obj = document.createElement("DIV");  
        obj.innerHTML = "<span class=\"itemId\">" + list[i].Id   
                + "</span><!-- some more simple code --> ";  

        mainObj.appendChild(obj);
        i++;
    }
    else
        window.clearInterval(timer);
}, 1);
```

The obvious drawback is that this will take your loop longer to complete because it's fitting the rendering inbetween each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I wold do it like this using **jQuery** instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            timer = window.setInterval(function ()
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    $('#container').append('<div>testing</div><br />');
                }
            },10);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery does it so quickly, you won't even need to bother about showing as they are created, but you can make it smoother by adding a timer as the example shows.

Comment: jQuery can't make for loops and DOM creation any quicker.  In fact, jQuery's regular expressions for converting HTML to DOM nodes would make it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you want the DOM to be updated after every cycle?
It would be alot faster if you create all the elements in one javascript element, and add this one element to the DOM when the cycle is finished.

```
var holder = document.createElement("DIV");
for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {
   var obj = document.createElement("DIV");
   obj.innerHTML = "<span class=\"itemId\">" + list[i].Id 
                   + "</span><!-- some more simple code --> ";

   holder.appendChild(obj);
}
mainObj.appendChild(holder);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid browser freeze. If user will see that the rows adding to the page he will see the progress (in IE even progress showing image freeze).